# Reorganizing a sentence when it is long

Tags: sentence-construction

I think I can say

> An HTML web page, **in contrast with a plain text**, is commonly referred to as a semi-structured data source.

Now if the apposition is too long can I say

> An HTML web page is commonly referred to as a semi-structured data source, in contrast with a plain text which is considered an unstructured data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can

> An HTML web page is commonly referred **to** as a semi-structured data
>   source, in contrast with a plain text, which is **regarded as** an unstructured
>   data source.